# Not sure how to do database design

Tags: database, model

I am currently working on a database design shown as a table. I am not all that familiar when it comes to this topic so I am not sure if I am doing it right. I would like some feedback.

[image: database design]

Comment: There's no way to be sure if you're doing it right without you divulging what is the application and intended uses for such a table.

Comment: It is a tabbed view applications and the txt files are files that are read from with the application.